# MySQL Query doesn't check for condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query like this:

```
    select * from `research_purchases` left join `company_research_articles`
 on `research_purchases`.`researchable_id` = `company_research_articles`.`id` 
and `research_purchases`.`researchable_type` = 'Modules\Analystsweb\Entities
\CompanyResearchArticle'
```

The research_purchases table structure is like this:[image: research_purchases table]

It is not filtering the "Modules\Analystsweb\Entities\CompanyResearchArticle" part and giving me the entire result.
This is the part where I am stuck.

Originally I want to run a Laravel query.
The query is like this:

```
$sales = DB::table('research_purchases')->select(DB::raw('count(research_purchases.id) as sales_count, research_purchases.created_at'))->leftJoin('company_research_articles', function ($join) {
                                        $join->on('research_purchases.researchable_id', '=', 'company_research_articles.id')
                                            ->where('research_purchases.researchable_type', '=', 'Modules\Analystsweb\Entities\CompanyResearchArticle');
                                    })
                                    ->where('research_purchases.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonths(11))
                                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(research_purchases.created_at)"))
                                    ->get();
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you give me query i can help you. but I have no idea about laravel

Comment: The query is at the top of the post please check.

Comment: I have already given you a reason

Comment: check the length of one of the records and make sure the length is the same as the limit (51)  you likely have a non-display character causing the issue. (space, tab, end of line etc)

Answer (score 1):

ohh dear you should put this in where condition

if you want left join all data on where condition of right table then you put it with **join on**

```
select * from `research_purchases` left join `company_research_articles`
 on `research_purchases`.`researchable_id` = `company_research_articles`.`id` 

where  `research_purchases`.`researchable_type` = 'Modules\Analystsweb\Entities
\CompanyResearchArticle'
```

Comment: It gives zero results.

Comment: than check you where condition you have data completely like this

Answer (score 0):

Please try whereColumn .

```
$sales = DB::table('research_purchases')->select(DB::raw('count(research_purchases.id) as sales_count, research_purchases.created_at'))->leftJoin('company_research_articles', function ($join) {
               $join->on('research_purchases.researchable_id', '=', 'company_research_articles.id');
        })->whereColumn([
                    ['research_purchases.researchable_type', '=', 'Modules\Analystsweb\Entities\CompanyResearchArticle'],
                    ['research_purchases.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonths(11)]
        ])->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(research_purchases.created_at)"))
                             ->get();
```

or both the where in side the closer

```
$sales = DB::table('research_purchases')->select(DB::raw('count(research_purchases.id) as sales_count, research_purchases.created_at'))->leftJoin('company_research_articles', function ($join) {
                                        $join->on('research_purchases.researchable_id', '=', 'company_research_articles.id')
                                        ->where(
                    'research_purchases.researchable_type', '=', 'Modules\Analystsweb\Entities\CompanyResearchArticle')
                             ->where('research_purchases.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonths(11))
                )
})->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(research_purchases.created_at)"))
                                    ->get();
```